# Cannot find the class file for com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Latlng

Tags: android, github, actionbarsherlock, eclipse-adt

I was working about ActionBarSherlock, How can i fix it? in my google-play-services_lib i have my latlng.class but in my error description it cannot define the latlng.class please help me.

This is my 2 errors:

- The type com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Latlng cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Latlng. Fix the build path then try building this project

In my console tab:

```
[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock] Versions found are:

[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock] Path: C:\Users\joma\Desktop\workspace\GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\libs\android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar
[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock]   Length: 38334
[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock]   SHA-1: bbd8a6ac0de84f30a15f1f6b11f61e8387da3db0

[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock] Path: C:\Users\joma\Desktop\workspace\gridlayout_v7-master\libs\android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar

[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock]   Length: 38334

[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock]   SHA-1: 87d4ee6826a41fd3d2680d4f9ee63334455265a6
[2014-10-29 20:46:33 - GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I tried to build the path again but nothing happened, i tried also to download again the **google-play-service_lib** and import but nothing happened with the error

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different support library remove one of it and set references of removed to not deleted library.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have mentioned the error .So the problem is that you have not properly refered the library

First right click your project  then click Build path->configure build path-> In the properties of the project select Android(then on the right side you can list of name so there click Android) .

Check whether the library google-play services is added .....check whether there is green colour tick
If you dont see the green tick ,that means you are wrong in adding the lib.

Also check whether you import the lib into your workscape :-

Step 1:-Import -> Project -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace , check copy to workspace and browse to where your android sdk folder is located: < android sdk folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Step 2:-Click Finish